# Pip Install Local v.s Remote Repository Confusion

Tags: python, django, pip

I am confused as to what exactly `pip install (package)` does. In my django project, I wanted to install a package and thought that I only needed to include it in the `settings.py INSTALLED_APPS`. However I also needed to run the command `pip install (package)` as well.

Why is this the case? I thought that pip install only installed packages locally? The package seems to also work through my remote repository from another user as well which is why I am confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip` is a package manager. When you `pip install (package)`, it searches PyPI (the Python Package Index) for a package with the name (and potentially, the version) that you have provided. It then downloads the package and installs it.

After the package has been installed locally, you can reference it in your `INSTALLED_APPS` in your Django settings file.

Please read more details here: https://realpython.com/what-is-pip/

Comment: I see. So if I have another person get my project files, will he or she be unable to have certain functionality unless they install the same packages?

Comment: They will need the same packages, which is why most Python projects include a `requirements.txt` file with the list of packages. These can then be installed via `pip`. https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#example-requirements-file

Comment: Comment makes the explanation much more sense, thank you!